# Can't read_excel a temporary file

Tags: r, temporary-files

I am using the code:

```
GET(myurl, authenticate(":", ":", type="ntlm"), write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")))
read_excel(tf)
```

I have checked that myurl is correct and is indeed a .xlsx file. 
The url command (before GET) goes through with no problem. 
The GET command also goes through with no apparent problem. 
But the read_excel command gets this:

```
Error: Evaluation error: zip file '/private/var/folders/ll/ts8m59zj2llc0yb0981f5jq40000gn/T/RtmpmrNRip/file395e33dc7710.xlsx' cannot be opened.

The private//// directory does contain the file I want. So I know url and GET did their job.
```

I have no idea why it thinks it's a zip file and it can't open it.
The file is indeed a proper .xlsx file.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sometimes it's because the file is opened (locked) by another process. Those errors have been notoriously non-specific-enough. (If you search on SO even, just for `[r] read_excel zip file cannot be opened`, then you'll get plenty of other questions that contain different candidate solutions/workarounds/troubleshooting-steps for this error. Some might apply.)

Comment: This might be due to (among many many other things) an interrupted, corrupted, or not-binary download. Since you don't really need authentication here, try `download.file(myurl, (tf1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")), mode = "wb")` and then try `readxl::read_excel(tf1)`.

Comment: Thanks r2evans! Your "notoriously non-specific" and"among many other things" is right on the mark! Your download.file suggestion works like a charm. Maybe the authentication made it hard to read after? In any case it works. Best

Comment: I saw that command, with `authenticate(":",...)`, on a recent question referencing covid-19 data, is that where you got it? I'm not familiar with the `":"` thing, perhaps it's a carry-over from a project that actually required authentication. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯